# How we can use Captcha in Sitecore Forms?

Tags: sitecore-forms

How can we show Captcha using Sitecore Forms and validate?

Comment: This blog link is not working. Can you please provide the proper link

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't exist such a field out of the box.

@Bart Verdonck created a module :  https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions which has a control to support google reCaptcha.

You can download it from : https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/tree/master/downloads

He has a series of blogposts about his module:

http://onelittlespark.bartverdonck.be/category/sitecore-forms-extensions/